# How to use dictionary in django template

Tags: django

i want to filter out the of promotion count, and save the service_type and promotion code for that particular count

here is my view

```
promotions=Promotions.objects.filter(member=request.user)
        dictt={}
        for promotion in promotions:
                c=customer_request.objects.filter(promotion=promotion)
                e=c.count()
                dictt[e]=e
                for w in c:
                    coupon_code=Promotions.objects.get(pk=w.promotion_id)
                    dictt.update({e:{coupon_code.coupon_code,w.service_type}})
        sorted_dictt = sorted(dictt.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

and i am displaying dict on html as follows

```
{% for a in sorted_dictt  %}
             <tr>
                <td style="color:#f38619;"></td>
               <td style="color:#f38619;">{{a.1}}</td>
                <td style="color:#f38619;">{{a.0}}</td>
               </tr>
              {%endfor%}
```

now i am getting result as:

[image: here is my display]

it should be display as

[image: it should display as]

how to do it?

Comment: use a.1.0 and a.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The following line looks wrong:

```
# Here, dictt[e] is a set that contains coupon_code.coupon_code and w.service_type
dictt.update({e:{coupon_code.coupon_code,w.service_type}})
```

Instead, write:

```
dictt.update({e: coupon_code.coupon_code})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use dictionary like this:

```
{% for key, value in dict.items %}
  {{key}}-{{value}}
{% endfor %}
```